# How to export Period data from one Salesforce Org to another

Tags: data-loader, data-import

I tried migrating Period from one Sales force org to another through Data Loader and Data Import Wizard but none of them supports this object.

Data Loader only lets you export from Period but I can't insert Period using Data Loader.Please tell me some way to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

As per the workbench, create permission is not available.
[image]

So you won't be able to create records vai data loader.

Comment: Yeah,but I got to do this somehow, any other way ?

Comment: @Sugandha I think here we are out of luck, since I tried performing dml operation on Period but it is giving below error. "COMPILE ERROR: DML operation INSERT not allowed on Period
LINE: 2 COLUMN: 1"